# How to create mapping using automapper for this complex object which contains member functions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

The function want to convert is using automapper is below

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Func<int,string> _roleName=t=>{return new RolesDAO().getROLEsByID(t).ROLE_NAME; };
        Func<int,string> _STATENAME=t=>{return new StateDAO().getStatesByID(t).STATENAME; };
        Func<int,string> _COUNTRYNAME=t=>{return new CountryDAO().getCountrieByID(t).COUNTRYNAME; };
        //Func<int,string> _TYPE_NAME=t=>{return new UsersTypeDAO().getUsersTypeByID(t).TYPE_NAME; };

        string usertypeName = string.Empty; 
        string RoleName = string.Empty;
        string StateName = string.Empty;
        string CountryName = string.Empty;
        var value = objDAO.getUsers().Select(t => new UsersVM
        { 
          ACTIVE=t.ACTIVE,
           ROLENAME=_roleName(t.ROLEID),
            PROFILE_IMAGE=t.PROFILE_IMAGE,
          STATEName = _STATENAME(t.STATE),
          COUNTRYName = _COUNTRYNAME(t.COUNTRY),
           MOBILE=t.MOBILE,
            FNAME=t.FNAME,
            LNAME=t.LNAME,
             EMAIL=t.EMAIL,
              CITY=t.CITY,
          USERTYPENAME = _TypeName(t.USER_TYPE_ID),
           ADDRESS=t.ADDRESS,
        }).ToList();

        return View("list", value);
    }
```

I used automapper function call for member but no success, I can't even debug using breakpoint. Please suggest how to convert this object to another object. I looked into many blog post but I am not able to relate that to my problem.

All I want to use automapper for this conversion instead of Creating Anonymous type and using functions in it.

I tried to use .forMember function but it is not working returning null for converted properties. Here is my profile class:

```
 public class UsersDM_TO_VM : Profile
{
    public UsersDM_TO_VM()
    {
        Func<int,string> _roleName=t=>{return new RolesDAO().getROLEsByID(t).ROLE_NAME; };
        Func<int,string> _STATENAME=t=>{return new StateDAO().getStatesByID(t).STATENAME; };
        Func<int,string> _COUNTRYNAME=t=>{return new CountryDAO().getCountrieByID(t).COUNTRYNAME; };
        Func<int,string> _TYPE_NAME=t=>{return new UsersTypeDAO().getUsersTypeByID(t).TYPE_NAME; };
        CreateMap<STBL_ADMINUSERS, UsersVM>()
            .ForMember(
            a => a.STATEName,
            b => b.MapFrom(c => _STATENAME(c.STATE)))
            .ForMember(
            d => d.ROLENAME,
            e => e.MapFrom(f => _roleName(f.STATE)))
             .ForMember(
            g => g.COUNTRYName,
            h => h.MapFrom(i => _COUNTRYNAME(i.STATE)))
             .ForMember(
            j => j.USERTYPENAME,
            k => k.MapFrom(l => _TYPE_NAME(l.STATE)));

    }
}
```

However it is not giving any error but unexpected result. No success with custom type converters also.

```
public class CustomUserConverter : ITypeConverter<STBL_ADMINUSERS, UsersVM>
{
    Func<int, string> _roleName = t => { return new RolesDAO().getROLEsByID(t).ROLE_NAME; };
    Func<int, string> _STATENAME = t => { return new StateDAO().getStatesByID(t).STATENAME; };
    Func<int, string> _COUNTRYNAME = t => { return new CountryDAO().getCountrieByID(t).COUNTRYNAME; };
    Func<int, string> _TYPE_NAME = t => { return new UsersTypeDAO().getUsersTypeByID(t).TYPE_NAME; };

    public UsersVM Convert(STBL_ADMINUSERS s, ResolutionContext c)
    {
        UsersVM t = new UsersVM();
        t.ROLENAME = _roleName(s.ROLEID);
        t.COUNTRYName = _COUNTRYNAME(s.COUNTRY);
        t.STATEName = _STATENAME(s.STATE);
        t.USERTYPENAME = _TYPE_NAME(s.USER_TYPE_ID);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a custom type converter. A type converter will allow you to completely control how AutoMapper maps from the source type to the destination type.

[Custom Type Converters](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters)

Comment: a tried to understand that example but i could not ,can u please explain ho w it will work for atleast this one property ROLENAME=_roleName(t.ROLEID)  using custom convertor ..